# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_pcap_findalldevs"

Tags: xcode, c++11, networking, pcap, libpcap

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pcap_findalldevs", referenced from:
      allNetworkDevices() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

in the manPage is nothing about libraries or something like that - what I have to do?
I made a 'clean' before build.
and also: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

--Now:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pcap_findalldevs", referenced from:
      allNetworkDevices() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And: Where can I set this '-v'

Comment: Did you try `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and Product->Clean?

Comment: the lib cap is not built for x86_64 bit simulator,  get the lib which supports all the architecture